# Converting protobuf.js Types to custom formats

Tags: protobuf.js

In my protobuf schema, I have a type that contains binary data (already defined in an existing schema, I can't change this):

```
// message BinaryKey { bytes data = 1; }

let BinaryKey = new Type('BinaryKey')
BinaryKey.add(new Field('data', 1, 'bytes'))
```

In my application JSON, I have a human readable string format of this field/type and would like to use this string for my field that is passed to `encode()`. What is the correct way to have `encode()` and `decode()` use custom conversion functions between string and binary format?

A full example of my code (using protobuf.js reflection):

```
let BinaryKey = new Type('BinaryKey')
BinaryKey.add(new Field('data', 1, 'bytes'))

let Message = new Type('CustomMessage')
Message.add(new Field('balance', 1, 'uint32'))
Message.add(BinaryKey)
Message.add(new Field('bin_key', 2, 'BinaryKey'))

let object = { balance: 100, bin_key: '<String representation>' }; // <-- *** pass in the data as a string to be converted
Message.encode(object).finish();
```

I would need to specify conversion functions between my string format and the binary field of the schema, but don't know how to add these to my `Type` (`BinaryKey`)